# Previewing an Image in Edit Text Android

Tags: android

Here's what I am planning to do.

1. Select Image from Gallery to Upload
2. Before Uploading, show the preview in `<EditText>`.

I'm stuck on how to preview the image.
Called `<ImageView>` before `<EditText>`, but that covered the `<EditText>` fully and I'm not able to use the textbar.

Any thoughts? 
Idea is similar to a preview of a url in Whatsapp's `<EditText>`.

**EDIT**

This is what my current xml looks like

[image: This is what my current xml looks like]

As you can see, there is an `<ImageButton>` from where I select my image. 
After selecitng the image, the image preview should come in the `<EditText>`.

Is the question clear now?

Comment: Totally unclear what you are asking!  EditText only takes "Text" not images.

Comment: @Booger, think he means that the ImageView is above (Z axis) his EditText and he can't select the ET. Not sure either.... Show us your xml or if you can rephrase, it would help a lot.

Comment: @Adrian-AlexandruComan that's precisely what I meant. Can it be displayed inside an `<EditText>`?

Comment: instead of showing it in edittext, you can hide your edittext!

Comment: even if it can it's extremely bad design.. Like name indicates `EditText` is for text.. You can put second imageView under your current and show preview there.. But if you still want to do it you can set background of edittext as a image..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if the user sees it inside the 'EditText' it doesn't have to be literally inside it. Gonna take a swing at answering.

Presuming that your xml may look something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
..../>
   <ImageButton/>
   <EditText/>
   <Button/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

You could make it something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
..../>
   <ImageButton/>
   <RelativeLayout>
       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imageView"/>
       <EditText
           android:bellow="@id/imageView"/>
   </RelativeLayout>
   <Button/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

You can have the ImageView's visibility set to GONE and make it VISIBLE only when you want to display it (the user selected a photo). You will still have to style the elements so they look good and do some other tweaks for UX purposes.

As well, depending on what you need, you could replace the inner RelativeLayout with a LinearLayout.

Comment: :p that pretty much does it. So, its answered by deceiving the human brain lol